# Issue testing an Angular service with abstract class dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service, which requires a dependency to another service, which in turns requires dependencies on two abstract classes.

```
(ThemeConfigService -> (SettingsService -> SettingsLoader, NavigationLoader))
```

I have gotten so far as to have the test fail because it cannot find the methods exposed via the abstract classes (not a function exception).

I'm not sure how I would get passed this, various searches online have not proved very helpful.

Here is the theme configuration service for which I'm trying to flesh out a test "`theme-config.service.ts`"

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThemeConfigService {

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private router: Router,
    private settings: SettingsService
  ) {
    // code removed for brevity
  }
}
```

Here is the service being tested "`settings.service.ts`"

```js
@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {

  constructor(public settingsLoader: SettingsLoader,
              public navigationLoader: NavigationLoader) { }

  public settings(): Observable<any> {
    return this.settingsLoader.retrieveSettings();
  }

  public navigation(): Observable<any> {
    return this.navigationLoader.retrieveNavigation();
  }
}
```

Here is the `SettingsLoader` class, the `NavigationLoader` looks exactly the same. They have to be separate classes from a design perspective:

```js
export abstract class SettingsLoader {
    abstract retrieveSettings(): Observable<any>;
}
```

My unit test looks something like this:

```js
describe('ThemeConfigService', () => {
  let service: ThemeConfigService;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
      providers: [
        Platform,
        SettingsService,
        SettingsLoader,
        NavigationLoader
      ]
    });

    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    service = TestBed.inject(ThemeConfigService);
  });

  it('should be created', async(inject([Platform, Router, SettingsService, SettingsLoader, NavigationLoader],
    (platform: Platform, router: Router, settings: SettingsService, settingsLoader: SettingsLoader, navigationLoader: NavigationLoader) => {

    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  })));
});
```

The error returned by Karma is:

```
TypeError: this.settingsLoader.retrieveSettings is not a function
which to me proves that it cannot resolve the abstract classes.
```

For that reasons have I gone ahead and created something like this:

```js
export class SettingsFakeLoader extends SettingsLoader {
    retrieveSettings(): Observable<any> {
        return of({});
    }
}
```

And tried changing the injection of the `SettingsLoader` and `NavigationLoader` classes with these, then Karma responds with:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ThemeConfigService -> SettingsService -> SettingsLoader -> SettingsLoader]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for SettingsLoader!
```

The amended `beforeEach` for the `theme-config.service.spec.ts` file:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
        RouterModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
        ],
        providers: [
        Platform,
        SettingsService,
        SettingsFakeLoader,
        NavigationFakeLoader
        ]
    });

    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    service = TestBed.inject(ThemeConfigService);
});
```

Usually, I would not try and test something I perceive to be this complex. Maybe I'm just not seeing the 'solution'.

The answers for this will be useful, as I'll have a similar scenario to resolve later down the line of this application's development.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good example of what you're trying to do in the [Angular testing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency):

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // stub UserService for test purposes
  userServiceStub = {
    isLoggedIn: true,
    user: { name: 'Test User' },
  };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ],
     providers: [ { provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceStub } ],
     // ^^^^^^ Note use of `useValue` ^^^^^^
  });

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
  comp    = fixture.componentInstance;

  // UserService from the root injector
  userService = TestBed.inject(UserService);

  //  get the "welcome" element by CSS selector (e.g., by class name)
  el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.welcome');
});
```

You can make an instance of any class that implements your Service's public API, then provide that instance with `useValue` when configuring the test module.  Calling `TestBed.inject(UserService)` will pass that value to the constructor of your dependent Service.

In your case, you can use `jasmine.createSpyObj<SettingsLoader>("SettingsLoader", ["retrieveSettings"])` to create an instance that implements the `SettingsLoader` API, then pass it to `providers` as `useValue`.  Now, `TestBed.inject(ThemeConfigService)` will call the real `SettingsService` constructor, passing it the spy object you created, then call the `ThemeConfigService` constructor, passing it the resulting `SettingsService` instance.

It's probably a good idea to switch to this model instead of the one in your answer, because if in future you e.g. update your `Platform` to depend on `SettingsService`, you'd suddenly find yourself in a situation where part of your code is using DI (`platform` and `router` are created with `inject(...)`) but part of it isn't (you're `new`-ing `SettingsService` and `ThemeConfigService` yourself).  Better to configure DI properly up front, and allow the injector to create all instances for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here I will develop a little [Coderer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64787491/860099) - where instead useValue I use useClass

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    { provide: SettingsLoader, useClass: SettingsFakeLoader },
    ...
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
```

So the pattern is: add to `providers` section following service

```
{ provide: AbstractService, useClass: FakeService }
```

(where FakeService class is implementation of AbstractService class)

Answer (score 0):

I went the instantiation route, instead of relying on the dependency injection. This might not be a viable solution, and would still like an answer on the original question from someone with a better approach.

The updated `describe` for the `theme-config.service.spe.ts` file:

```js
describe('ThemeConfigService', () => {
  let service: ThemeConfigService;
  let sLoader: SettingsLoader;
  let nLoader: NavigationLoader;
  let sService: SettingsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
      providers: [
        ThemeConfigService,
        SettingsService,
        SettingsLoader,
        NavigationLoader
      ]
    });

    let platform = TestBed.inject(Platform);
    let router = TestBed.inject(Router);

    sLoader = new SettingsFakeLoader();
    nLoader = new NavigationFakeLoader();

    sService = new SettingsService(sLoader, nLoader);
    service = new ThemeConfigService(platform, router, sService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```